# Is there an Eclipse add-on to build a python executable for distribution?

Tags: python, eclipse, bytecode

I want to build an executable to distribute to people without python installed on their machines.

Is there an add-on to Eclipse that allows this? I couldn't find one.

If not, do you have a builder that you recommend that would make it easy to go to my python project directory created in Eclipse, and bundle it all up?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106725/how-to-bundle-a-python-application-including-dependencies-for-windows) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116657/how-do-you-create-an-osx-applicationdmg-from-a-python-package)

Answer (score 1):

It's not eclipse, but ActiveState's [ActivePython FAQ](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/faq/windows/index.html#where-is-freeze-for-windows) mentions the freeze utility, which sounds like it might be close to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, there's the [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) project.

There's [bbfreeze](http://systemexit.de/bbfreeze/README.html), and [PyInstaller](http://pyinstaller.python-hosting.com/), and [py2app](http://www.undefined.org/python/), also.

Answer (score 0):

There is also PyInstaller:
http://www.pyinstaller.org/