# How to create a native Mac installer file for an adobe AIR application?

Tags: macos, air, installation, package

How to create a native Mac installer file for an adobe AIR application? Can i create it by using windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X, Flash Builder will create a .app file if you [export a release build with a captive runtime](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-13a250c812e8e9b5533-7ff9.html).  It will only work on OS X, though.

From there, you can create a .dmg to further package your app, as in: [How do you create an osx application/dmg from a python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116657/how-do-you-create-an-osx-application-dmg-from-a-python-package)