# OS X bundle for Common Lisp program

Tags: macos, lisp, bundle, common-lisp

So i wrote a program in Common Lisp and now have got it running in OSX. I have a "unix executable" that was created when dumping an image with :executable t.

My question started out as how to put the program on the dock (i ended up creating an alias of the executable and attaching it into the "stacks" area, where the trash bin is). However whenever I click on the alias it launches the terminal first, and the terminal then calls the executable.

So my question is how to get it to launch directly without calling the CLI?

Comment: ok so i've found a solution that seems to work from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116657/how-do-you-create-an-osx-application-dmg-from-a-python-package. however I now have a different issue, the locale setting in the .app file is not set to UTF-8 but to ASCII. does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after trying out several things, I've come to the conclusion that the solution I found above, although it let me create the `.app` bundle that was callable from OSX's Finder, was either incomplete, or I just couldn't figure out how to get my system to read my manually created `info.plist` where I had set the language in `LSEnvironment` to UTF-8. XCode wouldn't open the file, saying it was corrupted, though I just copied an existing file and edited the entries.

So I just ended up writing a script to call my program:

```
#!/bin/zsh
open -a ~/bin/locker
```

Then I used [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to create an `.app` bundle from the script and it just works! I still had to set the language in `LSEnvironment` to UTF-8, this was done with XCode and this time it didn't compain, the previous (manually created) `info.plist` file was written in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you solved your main problem.
on the localization question , what happens if you run the app through the terminal
and prepend  LANG=en_US.UTF-8?

For a more generic solution check out these two links: [cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92321-changing-the-locale-for-single-app.html), [mactipsandtricks](http://www.mactipsandtricks.com/articles/Wiley_HT_appBundles2.lasso)

Comment: Running through the terminal is fine, which is why i didn't notice this issue before. I'll look into the links thanks.