# "Pack" a script for others

Tags: python, macos, package

I have written a little script, with python 3 and on Linux. I would like to give it to my colleagues, who are essentially on Mac OS. Here are my imports:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import xlrd
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
from clize import clize, run
```

Normally, all these libs exist for python 2 and 3. I would like to make a kind of package for my team, easy to use for them, but I know almost nothing about Mac OS. Is there a way to do that ? I don't need it very clean, it's just an inside program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This link from Dive into Python might be helpful to you. Basically, it is centered towards distutils use for packaging.

[Packaging Python Libraries](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/packaging.html)

Another useful site is from python documentation itself.
[Distributing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/)

Also take a look at this other SO question about packaging specifically for Mac OS.

[How do you create an osx application/dmg from a python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116657/how-do-you-create-an-osx-application-dmg-from-a-python-package)